# how to solve these Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE or REPLACE  FUNCTION fun2(p_arg   IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN to_number(p_arg,'999,999.00');
  END fun2;
  BEGIN
-- calling the function   
  VARIABLE g_emp_sal number
      EXECUTE  :g_emp_sal := test_pack.fun2('33,600')
      PRINT    g_emp_sal
    end;CREATE or REPLACE  FUNCTION fun2(p_arg   IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN to_number(p_arg,'999,999.00');
  END fun2;
  BEGIN
-- calling the function   
  VARIABLE g_emp_sal number
      EXECUTE  :g_emp_sal := test_pack.fun2('33,600')
      PRINT    g_emp_sal
    end;
```

error
show error

> Errors for FUNCTION FUN2:
>
> LINE/COL ERROR
> -------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- 7/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" SQL>

Answer (score 1):

`variable` and `print` stuff don't belong to PL/SQL, but SQL*Plus.

```
SQL> CREATE or REPLACE  FUNCTION fun2(p_arg   IN  VARCHAR2)
  2      RETURN NUMBER
  3    IS
  4    BEGIN
  5      RETURN to_number(p_arg,'999,999.00');
  6    END fun2;
  7  /

Function created.

SQL> VARIABLE g_emp_sal number
SQL> EXECUTE  :g_emp_sal := fun2('33,600')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> PRINT g_emp_sal

 G_EMP_SAL
----------
     33600

SQL>
```

If you want to call function from PL/SQL, you can:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line(fun2('33,600'));
  3  end;
  4  /
33600

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```